# How do I override the base font size to 62.5%?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to override the base font size to 62.5%. I have added this code in my tailwind.config.js -

```
plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
        addUtilities({
            'html': {
                'font-size': '62.5%'
            }
        });
    })
]
```

With this approach, all the fonts in my project are looking small and other classes like margin, padding using this 62.5% as the base unit.

To make it work I have to manually overwrite their existing class to new unit in tailwind.config.js, which is too time-consuming. Is there any better solution to convert tailwind base font size to 62.5%?

```
plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
        addUtilities({
            'html': {
                'font-size': '62.5%'
            },
            '.text-xs': {
                'font-size': '1.2rem',
                'line-height': '1.6rem'
            },
            '.text-sm': {
                'font-size': '1.4rem',
                'line-height': '2rem'
            },
            '.text-base': {
                'font-size': '1.5rem',
                'line-height': '1.8rem'
            },
            ....
        });
    })
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tailwind has this as a built-in configuration. You may have to do some basic math. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size#font-sizes

Answer (score 1):

yo can do it by add this code to your input.css file

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

tip: you can change the extension tooltip with adding this command to your vscode settings `"tailwindCSS.rootFontSize": 10, // <- your root font size here`